# How to run INSERT ... SELECT in a dynamic PL/pgSQL statement?

Tags: json, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have a function that gets a PK, a name of a dynamic table and a JSON.
The dynamic table is created earlier.
I need to enter the data received in this table, for this I am using EXECUTE FORMAT, but I don't know how to use SELECT to throw all JSON to the table. The JSON has several objects.

Here's an example of the code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION FUNC_TEST(COD_FK BIGINT,
                              NAME_TABLE TEXT,
                              JSON JSONB)
    RETURNS VOID
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE FORMAT(
            'INSERT INTO public.%I (
                COD_FK,
                A,
                B,
                C) L%',
            NAME_TABLE,
            (SELECT COD_FK,
                    (SRC ->> 'A') :: TEXT,
                    (SRC ->> 'B') :: BIGINT,
                    (SRC ->> 'C') :: TEXT
             FROM JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(JSON) SRC));
END
$$;
```

The error that returns is:

```
ERROR: subquery must return only one column.
```

How can I perform this insert?

Comment: Looping throught the subquery results would be easy. Does that work for you?

Comment: Looping through the subquery results would be **messy**. Include the subselect in the dynamic query.

Answer (score 0):

The subquery should be part of the dynamic string:

```
EXECUTE
   format('INSERT INTO public.%I
              (COD_FK, A, B, C)
           SELECT %s,
                  (SRC ->> 'A') :: TEXT,
                  (SRC ->> 'B') :: BIGINT,
                  (SRC ->> 'C') :: TEXT
           FROM JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(%L) SRC',
          NAME_TABLE,
          COD_FK,
          JSON);
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly! +1